# when is an object created and can be referenced to?

Tags: android, instance-variables

I have a simple question but can't find the solution in the references anywhere.

When I create an instance of a certain class where the instance is to be propagated to a couple of places everytime it is created again the most obvious place where to put the code is in the creation method of the instance itself. This is how it would look like:

```
    public void MYTest() {

    public MYTEST() {
         ANOTHER_CLASS.myTest = this; // <-------- can I already use the new this and assign it ?
        }

    }
```

Can I put the assignments of this just newly created instance to other variables already in the creation method or do I have to write an extra "super" creation method like this and put this also in MYTEST:

```
public void MYTest() {

    public MYTEST() {
         ANOTHER_CLASS.myTest = this; // <-------- can I already use the new this and assign it ?
        }


    public static MYTEST superCreationMethodForMYTEST() {
        x = new MYTEST();  //      <- here for sure the creation of MYTEST instance is finished BEFORE the assgnment happens
        ANOTHER_ClASS.myTest = x;


        .... all the other assignments for x.....
            }
}
```

and then call it like

```
x = MYTEST.superCreationMethodForMYTEST();
```

instead of:

```
x = new MYTEST();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the `this` reference anywhere in the constructor.  However, it may not be wise, depending on your situation.  The main problem is that while the object exists at the time of the constructor, it is not completely constructed and therefore may not be in a state to handle method calls correctly.  If the assigned reference is used by an unsuspecting thread, for example, (or by a method called by your constructor) before your constructor (and any subclass constructors) finish, bad things may happen.

Edited to add: Your problem, as I understand it, is to make sure that a reference to the object is stored in particular places before whoever requested the creation of the object receives the newly created object.  One common pattern is to do basically what you surmise in your question, namely having a factory method (a static method) that uses `new` to construct the object and then stores it in the appropriate places.  This ensures that only references to a fully constructed object is stored.  At the same time, the actual constructor is declared `private` or `protected`  to prevent accidental use of `new` outside the factory method.

Comment: right, but if I just need to make sure that anytime this instance is to be created it is also assigned to all places where it is needed - being sure there is no call to it's method BEFORE we are done creating it (as an example an interafce object for cimmunication or anything like that). Is it really valid code to use the reference of an instance variable during it's creation time or is its REFERENCE only valid AFTER its creation method has finished?

Comment: The reference is valid inside the constructor, but what it refers to is an incompletely constructed object.  But a possible solution to your problem occurs to me now - I'll go add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that - that confirms what I thought - by the way is there anything in the references that defines this?